# Writing or to write?

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

"Peter is very good at (  ) stories" .
I chose 'to write' to fill ()but correct answer was 'writing'.
Can anyone explain why 'to write' was wrong and 'writing' is correct?

Comment: Have you searched the Internet for "gerund or infinitive"? You'll find a lot of answers there

Answer (score 1):

Some verbs only take a gerund as an object, such as write, keep, finish, practice, quit and recommend.

> Peter is very good at writing stories.

Some verbs only take an infinitive as an object, such as ask, agree, demand and hope.

> Peter agreed to write the story for homework.

Other verbs can take either, without a difference in meaning, such as like, love, hate and remember.

> Peter likes to write stories.
>
> Peter likes writing stories.

Still others can take either, but have a difference in meaning, such as forget, remember and stop.

> Peter stopped writing stories.
>
> Peter stopped to write a story.

Unfortunately, you're just going to have to learn which category a verb falls into through reading, listening and practicing.

Answer (score 1):

**At** is a preposition. As far as I know, a preposition cannot be followed by **to + infinitive.** Rather, it must be followed by a gerund (the -ing form). Let's consider similar constructions and see how the choice of verbs is irrelevant:

> He sucks **at swimming.**
> He excels **at cooking.**

And now some other prepositions:

> He always coughs **after running.**
> You can't make an omelet **without breaking** a few eggs.

So we do not have to memorize a long list of verbs to understand this particular rule.

You can find more examples at [Grammaring](https://www.grammaring.com/verb-preposition-gerund) and [voanews](https://learningenglish.voanews.com/a/everyday-grammar-gerunds-infinitives/2722827.html), among other sites.